# How can I disable Performance Counters in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2016

How can I disable performance counters for disk drives as well as others such as (I/O, Network etc). On Windows Server 2016 Disk performance counter is not avaliable yet on LTSB 2016 it is.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

The following does not work.

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PartMgr" /v EnableCounterForIoctl /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr" /v EnableCounterForIoctl /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VolMgr" /v EnableCounterForIoctl /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\I/O System" /v "CountOperations" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\I/O System" /v "DisableDiskCounters" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a `cmd.exe` as admin and run the command  `diskperf –n` and reboot. This [disable the disk performance counters](http://tweaks.com/windows/37020/turn-off-disk-performance-monitors/).

Comment: Does not work or hide the performance counters on Windows 10 LTSB. Tested.

Comment: have you made the required reboot? Also do you use the July 2015 or 1607 LTSB version?

Comment: Yes I did the reboot. I use 1607. On Server 2016 it is hidden the next time you open task manager.

Comment: do the opposite from here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-windows/troubleshooting/missing-process-performance-counters set the value to 1 and reboot. Also related: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2010/03/04/two-minute-drill-disabled-performance-counters-and-exctrlst-exe/

Comment: That doesn't work also.

Comment: hm, I'll ask my Microsoft contacts about the issue and post what I hear from them

Comment: Yes on LTSB 2016 "diskperf -N" temporarily(it is back after restart) stops the performance counters but the drive is still there. It is gone in Server 2016.